# だとする、うえで、よう in this sentence

Tags: grammar, usage

> 総会のあと、公明党大阪府本部の佐藤代表は、記者団に対し、都構想そのものへの賛否は白紙**だとしたうえで**、「法定協議会が再開されれば、いい協定書を作れる**よう**前向きに協力していくというのがわれわれのスタンスだ」と述べました。 ([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20190511/k10011912861000.html))

Here is my attempted translation:

> After the general meeting, the representative of the New Komeito Party Osaka Prefecture Administration, Mr. Sato, told to reporters, when **assuming** the opinions on both sides towards the Metropolis Plan have not been made, "If the statutory committee is reopened, our stance is that we will positively cooperate together to make a good agreement".

What does だとした mean? From what I know, だとする could mean "assuming that, when used with a noun"

> 彼の死は事故**だとする**君の推定は間違っているようだ。
> Your **assumption** that his death was an accident seems to be wrong.
>
> 病院は頭痛の原因を睡眠不足**だとした**。
> The hospital **assumed** the cause of the headache to be a lack of sleep.

But I'm not sure if this interpretation is correct for that sentence.

Also, is うえで the same type of 上で like in this example?

> これまた西欧文明を理解する**うえで**、忘れてはならないことでありましょう。
> Again, let's not forget this **when** trying to understand Western European civilization.

I translated it as "when"

And lastly, what does the **よう** in いい協定書を作れる**よう**前向きに協力していく mean? I assumed it was ように but I never seen it without the に before. Like in this sentence:

> 風邪を引かない**ように**ちゃんと寝てください。Get some sleep so you don't catch a cold.

---

Here are my questions:

1. Is my interpretation of だとする correct?
2. Is my interpretation of うえで correct?
3. What does よう mean?

Answer (score 1):

You understand everything correctly. There is no such thing as だとする. It's とする and だ is just there because there was a noun. If it was a verb or adjective you'd just use とする. And following this, obviously you can conjugate it.

Noun particles(?) like 為{ため}、様{よう}、余{あま}り, don't necessarily need に after them to function.

Comment: Does "とした" really convey the idea of an "assumption" in this case, as opposed to simply referring to an assertion that 佐藤代表 made to the reporters? I interpreted the phrase beginning with 記者団に対し and ending with としたうえで as something more like "told reporters that no decision had been made on whether or not to support the Metropolis Plan itself and then said…"

Comment: It's not assumption. From weblio: そう考える、そう判断する、という意を表す。「その可能性もあるとしなければならぬ」 「目標達成は難しいとされている」. He's plainly stating what happened. だとした上で would be more like "since...". I just noticed that part of your translation.

Comment: If とした does not mean "assumption" as you said, wouldn't my interpretation be incorrect? There's also this definition from weblio そのように仮定する意を表す。 「君がそこに居合わせた－・する」Can you please provide a clearer explanation?

Comment: I'm very sorry. I honestly didn't see this until now. I don't often use stackexchange... Anyway, what I meant when I said it does not mean assumption I meant in this particular case I don't believe it to mean an assumption, but rather an assertion. But this is just personal feeling because it feels strange to me for a news website to state assumptions instead of facts. I did say your understanding was correct because I do believe you understood the general idea, and that using the word assumption doesn't throw the sentence out of wack.